# Safari on iOS throwing a SyntaxError during javascript execution, but not on any other devices/browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, syntax-error, mobile-safari

When browsing our site (which is a Shopify store) on Safari on iOS, when the javascript is executed it throws a SyntaxError and stops the rest of the JS file from executing, breaking some of the other functionality. However, this doesn't happen on any other device or browser, only mobile Safari.

The error it throws is:

[image: SyntaxError]

Clicking on the file takes me to this section of code:

[image: Code snippet]

(This was all tested on an iPhone using BrowserStack, so I was able to access dev tools for error visibility)

I can't find anything wrong with the code at all, as it passes all validations I've tried, and as far as I can see, no invalid or illegal strings are used. All of elements listed exist on the page.

An example page with this code running is:
https://cancer.livebetterwith.com/products/ibeani-e-readertablet-cushion

But it happens on every product page on our site.

I've tried:

- Renaming the selector
- Renaming the attribute on the element
- Removing the selector it marked as having the error, but the browser just marked the next selector as erroneous
- Deleting all nodeSelectors and using the initial selectors dictionary

The specific section of code that it marks as erroneous is:

```
  /**
   * DOM node selectors.
   */
  setNodeSelectors() {
    this.form = null;
    this.target = null;

    this.nodeSelectors = {
      modal: document.querySelector(selectors.modal),
      form: document.querySelector(selectors.form),
      addToCart: document.querySelector(selectors.addToCart),
      charityAddToCart: document.querySelector(selectors.charityAddToCart),
      continueShopping: document.querySelector(selectors.continueShopping),
      buttonGroups: document.querySelector(selectors.buttonGroups),
      sections: [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors.section)],
      tabControls: [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors.tabControl)],
      tabContents: [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors.tabContent)],
      condition: document.querySelector(selectors.condition),
      charity: document.querySelector(selectors.charity),
    };
  },
```

But the whole file (pre-compiled) can be viewed here:

https://pastebin.com/49GLfmGi

I've spent about 4 hours trying to figure out what the issue is but I'm absolutely stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an invalid selector `[js-vat-exemption="addToCard`, you're missing `"]`. This is just before the line with the error and it is most probably what is causing it.

By the way, for this kind of selector (attribute with value), if the value doesn't contain spaces or any of these characters: `"` `'` `` ` `` `=` `<` `>` you can omit the quotes.

Comment: Oh my god I cannot believe I missed that. That's fixed it, thanks very much